# Maintain UITableView cell position with dynamic height cells after reloading source data iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In chat application, I am implementing **Load More** button on top of `chat table view`.

When user taps load more button, older messages (plus all the current messages which are present on screen) get fetched from DB (using `NSFetchedResultsController`) and then I am calling `reloadData()` method on `chat table view`.

I want to set the scroll position of tableview to the row which was top row before reloading table.

All the message cells are **dynamic in height** according to the message text.

I am using `auto layout` on storyboard.

My code:

```
let oldContentheight = _chatTableView.contentSize.height
_chatTableView.reloadData()
executeOnMain {
    if self.firstTimeFetching {
        self.firstTimeFetching = false
        self.scrollTableToLastRow(withAnimation: false)
        //this is for going to last cell when we come to chat screen
    }
    else {
        //after pressing load more button
        let newContentHeight = self._chatTableView.contentSize.height
        let newOffset = CGPointMake(0, newContentHeight - oldContentheight)
        self._chatTableView.setContentOffset(newOffset, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, declare property to save the indexpath of top visible cell

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) *topVisibleIndexPath;
```

Then when you click the **Load More** button, you get the top visible cell IndexPath and save

```
NSArray *visibelIndexpaths = [yourTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows];
if(visibelIndexpaths.count > 0)
    self.topVisibleIndexPath = [visibelIndexpaths firstObject];
```

After reload, you call method :

`[yourTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.topVisibleIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES`]

Comment: If your loaded data is appended old data, you should rely on the INDEXPATH of the TopCell.
You should check variable : var indexPathsForVisibleRows: [NSIndexPath]? { get } and method : func scrollToRowAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath,
           atScrollPosition scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition,
                   animated animated: Bool)

Comment: Use var indexPathsForVisibleRows: [NSIndexPath]? { get } to get oldIndexPath, after reload, call method scroll to scroll to origin indexpath

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `reloadData`, consider doing **batch updates**. `reloadData` will load up new elements from your dataSource, but it will also have a side effect of resetting your scrollView's scroll position to the top.

What you want is to use this pattern:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([/* new rows here as an array of NSIndexPaths */], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

where the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` contain the new rows you want to add.

Comment: You don't need to use `begin/endUpdates` if you only make one call to `insert/delete/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`.

Comment: Good to know, but would you need it to get dynamic cell sizing to work without jitteriness?

Comment: Yes, using `beginUpdates/endUpdates` with nothing else in between is a nice way to have row heights updated.

Comment: but how can I get index paths for newly fetched messages?